# Clojure map transformations (children to fathers in a tree)

Tags: clojure

Say I have the following map of nodes in a tree and their children:

```
(def a {0 [], 1 [], 2 [0, 1]})
```

Corresponding to a tree with node **2** at its root and two leaf-nodes **0** and **1** as node **2**'s children.

How do I transform it into a map of fathers, or, better yet, adorn it with the fathers. E.g. arrive at the following map of fathers:

```
{0 2, 1 2, 2 nil} ; each node only has one father at most
```

Or, better yet, at the following map which combines children and fathers:

```
{0 [[] 2], 1 [[] 2], 2 [[0,1] nil]}
```

Comment: What designates the root, is it the last one?

Comment: I reckon the root is the only one without a parent, i.e. not someone's child.

Comment: The one without a parent, you may assume only one root (a tree, not a forest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn parents [m]
  (let [plist (into {} (for [[k v] m vv v] [vv k]))]
    (into {} (map (fn [[k v]] [k [v (plist k)]]) m))))

(parents a)
=> {0 [[] 2], 1 [[] 2], 2 [[0 1] nil]}
```

Answer (score 4):

First bit:

```
(def a {0 [], 1 [], 2 [0, 1]})

(defn parent-map [m]
  (reduce 
    (fn [x [k v]] 
      (into x (zipmap v (repeat k)))) {} m))

(def parent (parent-map a))   

parent 
=> {1 2, 0 2}
(parent 1)
=> 2 
(parent 2)
=> nil
```

So, no need to have `2 nil` explicitly in the parent map.

Second bit:

```
(defn parent-child-map [m]
  (let [parent (parent-map m)]
    (reduce 
      (fn [x [k v]] 
        (assoc x k [(m k) (parent k)])) {} m)))

(parent-child-map a)
=> {2 [[0 1] nil], 1 [[] 2], 0 [[] 2]}
```

Something a tad more interesting:

```
(def b {0 [], 1 [], 2 [], 3 [], 4 [0 1 2], 5 [3], 6 [4 5]})

(parent-child-map b)
=>
{6 [[4 5] nil],
 5 [[3] 6],
 4 [[0 1 2] 6],
 3 [[] 5],
 2 [[] 4],
 1 [[] 4],
 0 [[] 4]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I wish I could accept both but I ended up accepting mobyte's since the comprehension seemed clearer to me once I got it.